# How to keep same reference, when logging in and going back to login page with "back arrow" ? (password stays in filed)

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, redirect

How can you keep the reference by logging in and then going back to the login page with "go back arrow" and still beeing on the same reference (users password should be still available).

This code below obviously does not do the trick.

Login_form

```
private void btn_admin_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Admin_Form().Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Admin_Form

```
private void Btn_back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Login_Form().Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "same reference"? Do you want the earlier-shown form to re-appear? Then don't do `new`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yeah, I want it basically to re-appear.

Comment: Then keep a reference to the `new()`ed form.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be aware between the difference of a [modal dialog box and a modeless dialog box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/modal-and-modeless-dialog-boxes?view=msvc-170)

- If a form opens a modal dialog box, then this dialog box must be completed (closed) before you can continue using the form. In other words: while the modal dialog box is open, you can't use the form. Example: File-Open dialog box
- If a form opens a modeless dialog box, then both the form and the dialog box can be active and used. If you close the modeless dialog box, the form remains. Example: a help form that is opened if you click menu item help (or quite often F1)

You want to show a login dialog box. While this login dialog box is open, you shouldn't be able to edit in the form. Usually this form remains visible, but you chose to deviate from the windows standard and hide the form until the login dialog box is closed.

You used the word "back". Windows standard is "Cancel". But if you want, you can use a Button with text "Back" in your login dialog box.

By now you should have gathered that your login dialog box is a Modal dialog box: as long as the Login dialog box exists, you should not be able to activate your form. As an extra you even want to hide the form.

We need a class that holds the LoginData that is entered by the operator:

```
private class LoginData
{
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    public string Password {get; set;}
}
```

### The main form

In your form class:

```
LoginData GetLoginData()
{
    LoginData loginData = null;

    // Before showing the Login form, you want to make this form invisible.
    // This is not windows standard and not needed,
    // as this form will automatically be disabled
    // so why deviate from this standard?
    // but if you really want to:
    this.Visible = false;
    
    // create the login form and show it:
    using (FormLogin form = new FormLogin())
    {
        // if needed set some properties, for example the last used userName
        form.UserName = this.LastUsedUserName;
        ...

        // Show the login form and wait until closed
        Dialogresult dlgResult = form.ShowDialog();

        if dlgResult == DlgResult.Ok:
        {
            // operator filled in form, and pressed OK
            // get the UserName and Password from the login form
            loginData = new LoginData
            {
                UserName = form.UserName,
                Password = form.Password,
            };
        }
        // else: operator pressed Cancel, ("Back"?) or the x on upper right
        // loginData remains null
    }

    // before returning show this form again
    this.Visible = true;

    return loginData;
}
```

We also need a method to check if the login is correct:

```
bool CheckLoginData(LoginData loginData) { ... } // TODO: implement
void Login(LoginData loginData) { ... }          // TODO: implement
```

The implementation is out of scope of your question

A method to get the login data and if correct do a LogIn is straightforward

```
void GetLoginDataAndLogin()
{
    LoginData loginData = this.GetLoginData();
    if (this.CheckLoginData(loginData))
    {
        this.Login(loginData);
    }
    // else: incorrect loginData, or no loginData at all
    // TODO: decide what to do. Inform operator?
}
```

Finally the method if the operator clicks the Login button

```
void btn_admin_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.GetLoginDataAndLogin();
}
```

Now you might wonder why I made all these small procedures. Well, the main reason is that these procedures make it easier to reuse the code, to unit test it, to make small changes.

For instance, suppose you also want to do this if the operator presses a menu item "login"

```
void OnMenuItem_Logon_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.GetLoginDataAndLogin();
}
```

Or if you want to change how the Logon is checked for correctness, you only have to change one method.

### The logon form

Use visual studio designer to add a Form. Add the textboxes for UserName and Password, add two buttons: OK and Cancel (or if you really want to deviate from windows standard: Back. Use visual designer properties to assign the correct DialogResult to the OK and Cancel buttons.

Add two public properties to the form to access the UserName and Pasword:

```
public string UserName
{
    get => this.TextBoxUserName.Text;
    set => this.TextBoxUserName.Text = value;
}

public string Password => this.TextBoxPassWord.Text;
```

Note: we can't set the Password, only the operator can do this.

I've hidden how the UserName and Password are communicated with the operator. If later you want to change this, for instance use a combo box with the last used UserNames, then users of this form (= software, not operators), won't have to change.

Note: the logon form does not know for itself whether it is used as a modal dialog box or a modeless dialog box. So if you want to change this later, you won't have to change this form.

Comment: I have two simple two buttons, one is for the user to login (he does not need a  password to login)  and the another button is for the administrator (he need to enter a password). So the thing is when tha admin logins, he is redirected to the admin form, when the user logins, he's redirected to the user form. On both form there a "back arrow" that redrect both admin and user to login form. So I just want to know how to implement the code that not every time I need to call eg."new Login_Form().Show()" , because  the Login_Form still exsists somewhere and I need to call it but I don't know how.

Comment: What is the advantage of keeping the login form alive? Does it really take more than one millisecond to create it? If an object implements IDisposable, then the designer of the object thought that it holds scarce resources that should be freed as soon as possible. So don't keep an IDisposable longer alive than needed.